# Classes and methods, with lists in Python

Tags: python

I have two classes, called "Pussa" and "Cat". The Pussa has an int atribute idPussa, and the Cat class has two atributes, a list of "Pussa" and an int catNum. Every class has some methods, with an `__init__`. So, I've to do this

"(f)  Now, our cats get a "Pussa" infection. Put 4 Pussa objects on all even-index cats on the list cats. 
First generate the 20 needed Pussa objects with consecutive numbers. 
Then copy the references of the Pussa objects to the corresponding cats."

I have done this piece of code, but I don't really know how to go on... I just started this year with Python and I'm lost.

```
listPussa = []
for x in range(1,21):
    x = Pussa(x)
    listPussa.append(x)

for cat in cats: #cats is a list of 20 cat objects
    if cat.getcatNum()%2 != 0:
        for i in range(21):
            cat.addPussa(i)
            i = i +1
```

The class Pussa is defined by:

```
class Pussa:
    ''' Class Pussa '''
        # (a) Define a private attribute idPussa

        def __init__(self, idPussa = None):
                self.__idPussa = idPussa


        # (b) Define a __str__ method that 
        def __str__(self):
                self.__idPussa = idPussa
                if idPussa is None:
                        return "Pussa sin número."
                else:
                        return "Pussa número = " + idPussa


        # (c) Define setIdPussa
        def setIdPussa(self, idPussa):
                self.__idPussa = idPussa


        # (c) Define getIdPussa
        def getIdPussa(self):
                return self.__idPussa
```

And the class Cat:

```
class Cat:
    ''' Class cat '''
        # (a) Define the init method with a private attribute called catNum and a list of pusses
        def __init__(self, catNum = None, listPussa = []):
                self.__catNum = catNum
                self.listPussa = listPussa

        # (b) Define the mixeta method  
        def mixeta(self):
                if len(self.listPussa) is 0:
                        return "Miau!", self.getcatNum(), "La llista de pusses esta buida"
                else:
                        for pussa in self.listPussa:
                                return pussa.getIdPussa()

                        return  "Miau!", self.getcatNum(), "El nombre total de pusses es ", len(self.listPussa)



        # (c) Define the setter function for catNum
        def setcatNum(self, catNum):
                self.__catNum = catNum

        # (c) Define the getter function for catNum     
        def getcatNum(self):
                return self.__catNum

        # (d) Define a setter for adding a Pussa in the list of pusses
        def addPussa(self, Pussa):
                self.listPussa.append(Pussa)


        # (e) Define the cleanCat method which removes all pusses from the cat, empty the list
        def cleanCat(self):
                if len(self.listPussa) is 0:
                        return
                else:
                        for i in range(len(self.listPussa)):
                                self.listPussa.pop(i)
```

Every help and comment is very helpful :)

Comment: Can you please be more specific with the expected result? And maybe post even more code, like the class definitions...

Comment: The problem description doesn't state whether there are at maximum five even-numbered cats. If there are more the rest of the instructions wouldn't make any sense though. Also it is not clear whether by `references of the Pussa objects` an actual reference to the object or `idPussa` is meant. Neither is clear whether `catNum` or the list index is relevant to the even condition. The purpose of `getcatNum()` is not clear, could as well use `cat.catNum`.

Comment: The atributte catNum is private, so i think i have to use getcatNum() no?

Comment: @user3328113 There is nothing like `private` in Python. That might apply to many other object-oriented languages though.

Comment: I mean, I defined it this way: __catNum. But, wait a minute, I'll add the rest of my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably something like this?

```
pussaIndex = 0
for cat in cats:
    if cat.getcatNum() % 2 == 0:
        # add the next four elements from `listPussa`
        for i in range(4):
            cat.addPussa(listPussa[pussaIndex])
            pussaIndex += 1
```